# Seeding relationships in Rails/ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, seed

In my db/seeds.rb file of my Rails 3.2.8 project, I create seed data:

```
level_1 = Level.create(number: 1)
```

My model for Level is:

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number
  has_many :lessons
end
```

So then I want to seed the lessons:

```
Lesson.create(number: 5, level: level_1)
```

Its model is:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :level_id, :number
  belongs_to :level
end
```

When I run `rake db:setup`, I get the following error:

> rake aborted! Can't mass-assign protected attributes: level

How do I get this to work, do I need to add `:level` to my list of `attr_accessible` elements in the Lesson model? Is this a bad idea? Should I instead simply create a `Lesson` without a `Level` and then afterwards call `lesson.level = level_1`?

***UDPATE***: The rails generated comments in the seeds.rb file shows this example:

```
cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to be able to mass-assign `level`? Put another way, will it be harmful if a form for Lesson objects can set the level attribute?

If it **will not** cause problems, go ahead and add it to `attr_accessible`, and keep doing what you're doing now.

If it **will** cause problems, use `.new` and set it manually:

```
lesson = Lesson.new
lesson.level = level_1
lesson.save
```

Comment: I don't understand what having level in `attr_accessible` does.  level_id is already by default in `attr_accessible`s list of attributes.  Wouldn't that allow a form for Lesson objects to set the level attribute?

Comment: @at. Ah. Yes, if `level_id` is already in `attr_accessible`, you aren't harming anything by adding `level` to it as well. Personally, I always add both, because I like the flexibility of mass-assigning by either name.